# View shrink ( not fade out ) using core animation

Tags: ios, core-animation

I have subclassed a `UIButton` to make the button shape appear as a doughnut ( circle with a transparent hole in the middle )

The `drawRect` is :

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];
    if(context==nil)
    context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:1.0 blue:0 alpha:0.5].CGColor);
    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
     CGContextSetLineWidth(context, self.frame.size.width/2 - innerRadius);

    CGPathAddArc(path, NULL, self.frame.size.width/2.0, self.frame.size.height/2.0, (innerRadius+((self.frame.size.width/2 - innerRadius)/2.0)), 0 * 3.142/180, 2.1 *3.14, 0);

    CGContextAddPath(context, path);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
    CGPathRelease(path);
}
```

When the button is clicked,  I want the inner hole to shrink gradually and finally disappear leaving the circle whole .

`innerRadius` controls the size of the inner hole so I used the following function to try to achieve what I want :

```
- (void) animateButton
{
       innerRadius = 0;

    [UIView transitionWithView:self duration:0.5
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                    animations:^{
                        [self.layer displayIfNeeded];
                    } completion:nil];
}
```

This works but not quite like I wanted. The hole just fades out over a 0.5 second period. I want it to gradually shrink and then disappear instead. How can I achieve this using core animation ?

Comment: I haven't used animation before but does using UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear instead of UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve do what you want?

Comment: @Lyssa No. This just removes the inner circle without any animation or delay.

Comment: Is this a questions about Core Animation because you want to use it or is it about UIView animations because that is what you are currently using?

Comment: I'd like to achieve this either way . I was trying UIView because I don't know how to approach using Core Animation

Comment: If you are going to use drawRect then you will need to create your custom animateble property, and move the drawing to a layer (instead of a view), another approach would be a shape layer where the path animated or a masking layer where a scale transform is animated.